# Capybara / Ruby - Trying to get only the Text from all ambiguous css selector and convert it to string

Tags: ruby, rspec, automated-tests, capybara

I'm trying to get all Texts from a specific CSS Selector that are ambiguous in the HTML. I would like to access these ambiguous css and get the Text and then return all that info.

I've figured out how to find all ambiguous selectors but I dont know how to get just the text from each selector.

The ambiguous selector is (it finds 3 matchers)
`.list-card-title .js-card-name`

**I've already tried commands like:**

`arr = Array(3)
 arr = find_all('.list-card-title.js-card-name').to_a
 puts arr.to_s`

When I use `puts arr`

I got the following output
`[#<Capybara::Node::Element tag="span" path="/HTML/BODY[1]/DIV[2]/DIV[2]/DIV[1]/DIV[2]/DIV[3]/DIV[1]/DIV[1]/DIV[3]/DIV[1]/DIV[1]/DIV[1]/DIV[2]/A[1]/DIV[3]/SPAN[1]">, #<Capybara::Node::Element tag="span" path="/HTML/BODY[1]/DIV[2]/DIV[2]/DIV[1]/DIV[2]/DIV[3]/DIV[1]/DIV[1]/DIV[3]/DIV[1]/DIV[1]/DIV[1]/DIV[2]/A[2]/DIV[3]/SPAN[1]">, #<Capybara::Node::Element tag="span" path="/HTML/BODY[1]/DIV[2]/DIV[2]/DIV[1]/DIV[2]/DIV[3]/DIV[1]/DIV[1]/DIV[3]/DIV[1]/DIV[1]/DIV[1]/DIV[2]/A[3]/DIV[3]/SPAN[1]">]`

Comment: what does ambiguous mean in this context?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the text of elements you need to call `text` on each of the elements. In your case the easiest way to do that would be

```
find_all('.list-card-title.js-card-name').map(&:text)
```

which will return an array of the text contained in each of the elements.  If you then want all of that concatenated into one string you could do

```
find_all('.list-card-title.js-card-name').map(&:text).join
```

Note: you have tagged your questions with `automated-tests`, are you actually testing an app/site, or are you instead doing web scraping?  If you are testing you'd be much better off writing your tests using Capybaras expectation/assertion methods (and the :text options they accept) rather than finding elements, extracting/manipulating contained text and then doing something (I assume asserting on) with that.